# ESP32 reading DHT22 sensor in ULP coprocessor

Tags: sensors, esp32

I´m trying to read a dht22 sensor in ulp deep sleep, and it´s not working, can perhaps someone tell me what I´m doing wrong?

I´m reimplementing the arduino-DHT library because it´s working in non ulp mode with my sensor, it looks like this:

```
 digitalWrite(pin, LOW); // Send start signal
 pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
 delayMicroseconds(800);

 pinMode(pin, INPUT);
 digitalWrite(pin, HIGH); // Switch bus to receive data

  // We're going to read 83 edges:
  // - First a FALLING, RISING, and FALLING edge for the start bit
  // - Then 40 bits: RISING and then a FALLING edge per bit
  // To keep our code simple, we accept any HIGH or LOW reading if it's max 85 usecs long

  uint16_t rawHumidity = 0;
  uint16_t rawTemperature = 0;
  uint16_t data = 0;

  for ( int8_t i = -3 ; i < 2 * 40; i++ ) {
    byte age;
    startTime = micros();

    do {
      age = (unsigned long)(micros() - startTime);
      if ( age > 90 ) {
        error = ERROR_TIMEOUT;
        return;
      }
    }
    while ( digitalRead(pin) == (i & 1) ? HIGH : LOW );

    if ( i >= 0 && (i & 1) ) {
      // Now we are being fed our 40 bits
      data <<= 1;

      // A zero max 30 usecs, a one at least 68 usecs.
      if ( age > 30 ) {
        data |= 1; // we got a one
      }
    }

    switch ( i ) {
      case 31:
        rawHumidity = data;
        break;
      case 63:
        rawTemperature = data;
        data = 0;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Looks simple enough :D, I tried the first part with this code, but it doesn´t work:

```
rtc_gpio_init(15);
rtc_gpio_set_direction(15, RTC_GPIO_MODE_INPUT_OUTPUT);
```

And in my ulp script file:

```
.set temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 13 // gpio 15 (adc 13)

send_start_signal:

    /* disable hold on gpio 15 (data pin) */
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_IO_TOUCH_PAD3_REG, RTC_IO_TOUCH_PAD3_HOLD_S, 1, 0)

    /* switch to output mode */
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_W1TS_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TS_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1, 1)

    /* send start signal (LOW) */
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1, 0)

    /* pull low for 800 microseconds (8Mhz) */
    wait    6400

    /* switch to input mode */
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_W1TC_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_W1TC_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1, 1)

    /* switch bus to receive data (HIGH) */
    WRITE_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_OUT_REG, RTC_GPIO_OUT_DATA_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1, 1)

wait_for_sensor_preparation_low:

    READ_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_REG, RTC_GPIO_IN_NEXT_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1)
    and r0, r0, 1
    jump wait_for_sensor_preparation_low, eq

wait_for_sensor_preparation_high:

    READ_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_REG, RTC_GPIO_IN_NEXT_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1) 
    and r0, r0, 0
    jump wait_for_sensor_preparation_high, eq

    jump wake_up // <-- never called :(
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "and r0, r0, 0" instruction (near the end) always sets r0 to zero (x & 0 == 0 by definition), which means the following jump instruction will loop forever.  Remember that the "eq" flag doesn't really mean "equal".  It means "zero". I think you want:

```
wait_for_sensor_preparation_low:

    READ_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_REG, RTC_GPIO_IN_NEXT_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1)
    and r0, r0, 1
    jump wait_for_sensor_preparation_high, eq
    jump wait_for_sensor_preparation_low

wait_for_sensor_preparation_high:

    READ_RTC_REG(RTC_GPIO_IN_REG, RTC_GPIO_IN_NEXT_S + temp_humidity_sensor_pin, 1) 
    and r0, r0, 1
    jump wait_for_sensor_preparation_high, eq
```

By the way, I wrote a C compiler for the ULP, which should make your life easier.  It's on https://github.com/jasonful/lcc

Comment: Thanks for your help and the clarification on the "eq" flag, it works now as expected. Was my first time coding in Assembler, will try your compiler, hopefully it was the last time :D